# Transpose a list

Tags: python

Suppose i have a nested list m = `[[2, 3], [4, 7]]` and I want to transpose it such that I get `[[2, 4], [3, 7]]`   OR if m can be `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]` then after passing through the transpose function i should get `[[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9]]`
It should also work for `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]` which returns `[[1,4],[2,5],[5,6]]`

```
def transpose(m):
    t = make_copy(m)  ##[[2, 3], [4, 7]]
    if len(t) == 1:  ## if [[1]]
        return t  ##[[1]]
    i = 0
    while i <= len(t): #0 <= 2
        t[0][i] = t[i][0] #t[0][0] = t[0]t[0] ## t[0][1] = t[1][0] so now 3 = 4
        i += 1  #1
        return t
```

I thought this should work but it didn't give me the answer I want. Whats wrong  ?

Comment: Now your example makes sense.  |=^]

Comment: Sorry just edited it.

Comment: I don;t understand why it doesn't work here. There is nothing wrong with my loop

Answer (score 5):

Use [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function

```
print zip(*[[2, 3], [4, 7]])
# [(2, 4), (3, 7)]
```

So, your transpose function becomes like this

```
def transpose(m):
    return zip(*m)

assert transpose([[2, 3], [4, 7]]) == [(2, 4), (3, 7)]
assert transpose([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]) == [
    (1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
```

Remember, it just returns a list of tuples. They can be used almost interchangeably, except for the facts that the syntaxes for creating them is different and tuples are immutable.

If you really want to get only list of lists, you have throw in a comprehension or a `map` function, like this

```
def transpose(m):
    return [list(item) in zip(*m)]
    # return map(list, zip(*m))

assert transpose([[2, 3], [4, 7]]) == [[2, 4], [3, 7]]
assert transpose([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]) == [
    [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
assert transpose([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]) == [[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
```

Comment: Zip function will not work for this case [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] which returns [[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]]. Question was unclear. Sorry.

Comment: @user3398505: Why would the last row there be `[5, 6]` instead of `[3, 6]`?

Comment: @user3398505 What do you expect for that input then?

Comment: Output should be  [[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]].

Comment: That's exactly the output this answer produces.

Comment: Note: If your data is M by N, this function will give you a result that's N by M - unless M is 0, in which case, the result will be an empty list, rather than an N by 0 list of empty lists.

Comment: @user3398505 Please check the answer now. It actually produces your expected answer only.